# Is mini displayport fully compatible with displayport and G-Sync?

Tags: displayport, mini-displayport, g-sync

I have a GTX 1080 video card in a laptop.  The laptop outputs Thunderbolt, Mini displayport and HDMI.  I read that G-Sync requires a displayport. I've seen [adapters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A7R9I22) to go from mini displayport to displayport v1.2.  Can I use my [ROG SWIFT PG248Q](https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-SWIFT-PG248Q/HelpDesk_Manual/) as an external monitor with a Minidisplay port as the input on the other end and still get the full capabilities of G-Sync?

The posts that say G-sync is not HDMI compatible are pretty old.  Is it still true that HDMI is not G-Sync compatible?

Please note that whatever I do, I want the capability to overclock the monitor to 180 Hz.

Comment: I ordered a DisplayPort to mini DisplayPort and will let you all know how it works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought a DisplayPort to mini DisplayPort cable with male adapters on both ends.  It works just fine.  I have G-Sync and I'm able to up the refresh rate to 144Hz.  And it seems to be able to handle OC up to 180Hz.  The only issue I had was that 3D enabled itself and I had a hard time turning it off.  Eventually the issue just went away.

Comment: Have you checked with HDMI cable only that g-sync working or not? Also if working then which max frame rate?